# Is this assertion of `const char*` guaranteed to be true?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, comparison, string-literals

Here is the code example(compiled and run in vs2015):

```
#include<cassert>
using namespace std;
int main() {

    const char*p = "ohoh";
    const char*p1 = "ohoh";
    char p3[] = "ohoh";
    char p4[] = "ohoh";
    assert(p == p1);//OK,success,is this always true?
    assert(p3 == p4);//failed

    return 0;
}
```

As far as I know,the string literals are stored in the `readonly` segment in address space,and  `const char*p = "ohoh";` just generate a pointer to that position.However,it seems like the compiler will just generate one copy of that string literal,so the `p==p1` is true.

Is it a optimization ,or something guaranteed by the standard?

Comment: The standard doesn't guarantee anything concerning `p` and `p1`, they might point to the same memory location or not.

Comment: It most likely isn't. There are optimization options for merging identical strings (String Pooling in VS), so that kind of implies compilers are not obligated to do it as per standard.

Comment: Isn't it the case, that `p3` and `p4` are separate arrays, that are both initialized with the same string literal.

Comment: @mschmidt yes, but `p3` and `p4` are not mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Michael-Walz, sure, but I think the question stems from the confusion about `p` and `p1` vs the behaviour of `p3` and `p4`. I.e. arrays and pointers are not the same thing.

Comment: @CookiePLMonster There are both options to get the compiler to conform to the standard, as well as others to force it to diverge. They normally are mostly for back-compat or efficiency.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it is not guaranteed by the standard. According to [cppref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal):

> The compiler is allowed, but not required, to combine storage for equal or overlapping string literals. That means that identical string literals may or may not compare equal when compared by pointer.

Answer (score 7):

The behavior is unspecified, you can't rely on it. From the standard, [[lex.string]/16](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.string#16)

> Whether all string literals are distinct (that is, are stored in nonoverlapping objects) and whether successive evaluations of a string-literal yield the same or a different object is unspecified.

For `p3` and `p4`, they're different things. Note that `p` and `p1` are pointers (to string literal) but `p3` and `p4` are arrays initialized from [string literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal#Notes).

> String literals can be used to initialize character arrays. If an array is initialized like `char str[] = "foo";`, `str` will contain a copy of the string `"foo"`.

That means `p3` and `p4` are independent arrays. When decay to pointer they'll be different (because they point to different arrays), then `p3 == p4` would be `false`.

Answer (score 1):

It is implementation defined whether equal string literals are stored by the compiler as one string literal. So this comparison

```
p == p1
```

can yield either `true` or `false` depending on the compiler options.

As for arrays then they do not have a built-in comparison operator.

Instead of

```
assert(p == p1);
assert(p3 == p4);
```

you could write

```
assert( strcmp( p, p1 ) == 0 );
assert( strcmp( p3, p4 ) == 0 );
```

Comment: It is **not** implementation defined. It is unspecified. The difference is that when something is implementation defined, a conforming compiler is **required** to document what it does.

Comment: @PeteBecker And it does document.:) See the description of the compiler options.:)

Comment: "Unspecified" does not mean "must not document". I neglected to mention that my comment is about the **definition** of those two **technical terms** in the C++ standard.

Answer (score 0):

String literals *may* share storage, and *may* be in read-only memory.

Neither is guaranteed though.

What is guaranteed is that two different arrays won't share space unless their lifetime does not overlap. In the latter case there's no conforming way to prove it anyway, so who cares?